# Get google searchResultTime with Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, google-search

I'm connecting to google.com/search?q=java using java's URLConnection. I'd like to get the search result time , but I don't know how to get it.

I also tried this with Selenium WebDriver and I can get the search result links , but not the time.

I looked at the contents returned by connection's InputStream , and couldn't find anything time related, so I'm not sure where to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following use the following xpath:

```
//div[@id='resultStats']//nobr
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I want the time from "About 439,000,000 results (0.32 seconds)" given by google after the search. What you are suggesting might be close to the same time but it's not te pure google search result time )

Comment: @April: Do you want to retrieve the time value shown on the search result page? If yes, please use the xpath: `//div[@id='resultStats']//nobr`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works, please update you answer and I'll accept it. And sorry if it's smth simple but how did you know to look for a nobr tag in div with resultStats id, I couldn't find anything in the page source code )

Comment: Please follow the image I posted here : http://s9.postimg.org/plbgjyy2n/locator.png. This will help you to understand how I inspected that element.